# pod install failed with error: Library (from `../`)` required by `Podfile` when pod install in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods

I am making a cocoapods. I am using `pod lib create MyLibrary` to create a new cocoapods. After it's done, I added two files into MyLibrary/Pod/Classes/. And I commit and add a tag and then push to origin master. and the MyLibrary.podspec passed validation. So, I go into the Example folder which created when I do `pod lib create MyLibrary`. and do a `pod install` in the terminal. But I am getting error:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `MyLibrary` from `../`
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `MyLibrary (from `../`)` required by `Podfile`
```

The podspec settings are all correct, like this one `s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/*.{h,m}'`, and it passed the validation. So I think there is no problem with pod spec file. It seems the pod installation can't find the Pod folder. But it is right there.

I am new to this making cocoapods. So if there is anything that not clear, please let me know. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: If you are installing the podfile for very first time, open terminal and mention cd <space> <drag and drop your entire project> -->touch podfile-->open podfile-->mention your pod name-->pod install

Comment: Please read from beginning. I am making a cocoapods. I am making a cocoapods, so people can use it and they can pod install my cocoapods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42164794/889289

Answer (score 29):

I had the same problem and I have been able to solve it following this steps:

- Update cocoapod
- Remove Podfile.lock
- Installing again

Commands:

```
$> sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
$> rm Podfile.lock
$> pod install
```

Maybe some are not necessary, but it worked for me (I think that the most important is to remove the Podfile.lock). I hope you can solve it too.

Comment: Removing Podfile.lock file and installing the pod again worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

Yeah. One hour I've just paid to solve this problem. The problem was  incompatibility of ios versions, a dependency had 7.0 but my target has 6.0 version. Updating to 7.0 the target version has solved my issue. Why wouldn't write an error message for such troubles?...

Comment: Same issue here. The auto-generated project from `pod lib create` set the iOS Deployment Target to 8.3. I required 9.1 in the podspec file. Changing the project's target to 9.1 resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I did the same and it got run perfect

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
$ sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
$ sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/
```

it works for me. I hope this solution will work for you too.

Comment: Hi mate, try to add a little description along your solution.

Comment: this is cleaning cocoa pods cache.

Answer (score 2):

I might be late, but if someone else finds this:

I often have the same problem, it happens when I use pod install in my own "MyLibrary" instead of pod update.

So try instead

```
pod update
```

This has to do something with your Podfile.lock, but I cant tell you exactly whats the reason.