# Cannot install Alamofire 4.0 in Xcode 8.0 Using CocoaPods

Tags: cocoapods, alamofire, xcode8

I need to upgrade one project to Swift 3.0, that has some libraries by Cocodpods.
So, I've removed all links related with Cocoapods and recreate pod file using pod init and upgrade some version of library such as AlamorFire.
But pod install said

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Alamofire (~> 4.0)` required by `Podfile`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Alamofire (~> 4.0)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

I've updated deployment Target to 9.0 and using cocoapod 1.1.0
For test, I've created new project and added only Alamofire, but the result is same.
If you have some experience, please help me.

Comment: Did you try running `pod repo update`?

Comment: Yes, I've updated.

Comment: While pod repo update, the error is occured by broken repository.
I've removed master repo and setup pod again.
After that, works well.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an outdated pod repo, pod install getting failed. First of all you have to update your pod master repo before running pod install. Follow the steps given to update your pod repo and resolve the pod error.

- Go to Cocoa Pods repo folder (**~/.cocoapods/repos**) and delete **master** folder
- Run `pod update` on terminal. This will take several minutes to update pod repo.
- When update get finished, run `pod install` (if required).

Hope this would be useful for those who are getting similar error :)

Answer (score 2):

try `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`

the pod file should look like

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'YourAPP' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/acegreen/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'swift3'
    pod 'NetReachability'
end
```